# what does "ほど" mean?

Tags: words

In the very famous song called "Chiisana Koi no Uta - 小さな恋のうた", there's a sentence:

> ほら　あなたにとって大事な人ほど　すぐそばにいるの

what does "ほど" mean here? I've tried to search, here're some results I've got:

- Look, the person who is that valuable to you is right beside you.(All sentence's translation)
- 大事なひとほど : the degree to which a person is important (?) / as valuable as a person (such?)
- ほど : degree, extent /to do smth as well as x (x ほど)

They make no sense to me. Anyone give help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「ほら、あなたにとって大事な人**ほど**すぐそばにいるの。」

It seems that you have overanalyzed things a bit.  Big words such as "***degree***" and "***extent***" are certainly relevant here with regards to comprehending how 「ほど」 functions in the sentence in question, but the moment you try to use those words in your translation attempt, things will fall apart immediately.

> 「A + ほど + B」 simply means:
>
> "The more A, the more B."

You will keep encountering this sentence pattern for as long as you study Japanese.  It is not only an important grammar point but also an extremely useful expression.

If you allow me to mix the two languages for a moment, here is what you need to be "seeing" in your head.

> 「ほら、あなたにとって the more 大事な人（は） the more すぐそばにいるの。」

Please note that unlike "the more", which is used **twice** in English,「ほど」 is used only **once** in this sentence pattern.

Thus, the sentence means:

> "***Look, the more important a person is for you, the closer s/he lives to you***."

Comment: Thank you very much. It's the same as I thought at first when I had tried to search on the internet. 本当にありがとうございました.