# Does [だけど] have some grammatical function with [ほど]？

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, particle-ほど

I saw this combination in the following part of a story:

> ステータスを見る限りではブラさんすら負ける**ほどだけど**、ブラさん的にはそんなに脅威ではないっぽい？

I read that normally ほど is used in several patterns, [for example](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53329/what-does-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9-mean/53331#53331) "A + ほど + B" to mean "The more A, the more B" and could have their meaning easily changed changing with what comes after the hodo by "[itself](https://maggiesensei.com/2012/10/10/how-to-use-%E7%A8%8B-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9-hodo/)".
But still I can't connect these information (if it's true) because with だけど, in my point of view (up to now) だけど is normally used in form of conjunction (alone) but being used straightly after hodo, makes my head confused.

**Context**

There were three subjects in the scene, with one their being the subject in the quotation above (being mentioned before the quotation by itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is けど rather than だけど in the first place.

The overall structure is

- ステータス...だ + けど、+ ブラさん...?

ほど by itself means degree. As a pattern AはBほどだ can be translated *A is about B* or *A is such that B*.

The implicit subject of the first clause is status, so it translates:

- Looking at the status, it (=the status) is such that even bura-san can be beaten

This should usually worry bura-san. The second clause says (the speaker's guess of being) otherwise, so it is connected by けど=*but*.

**[Edit]**

In above, it would be more precise to consider the person with that status as a subject, but I think in general it does not make much difference. To be even more precise,  you have to consider what quality is being talked about.

- Looking at the status, his/her strength/ability is such that he/she can beat bura-san; or
- ..., he/she is strong/good enough to beat bura-san.

As another example, consider

- 私の息子は大きくなって見上げるほどだ

which translates

- My son has grown up, he/his height is such that I have to look up (to see his face).

To get a proper translation, you have to think about all the implicit elements, of course. But in terms of understanding the sentence semantically, `AはBほどだ = A is such that B` looks good enough to me.

Comment: Isn't the implicit subject someone with that status?

Comment: @aguijonazo Yes. I didn't put it because I thought it would be embarrassing to specific the monster's name in the question.

Comment: @aguijonazo I agree, but see the edit for my comments.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but `ステータス` is not an explicit topic in this particular sentence. I would understand `ステータスを見る限りでは` to be implying it is one of multiple aspects of a hidden subject/topic, like saying “judging from its status alone, (A) is …

Comment: @aguijonazo I'll edit my question to give more context to it. I ended letting a blank space as to the subjects of the sentence.